# Optimum way to set OneToMany ManyToOne relations in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, search, optimization, one-to-many, many-to-one

Does anyone know which is the optimum way to set Hibernate relations for OneToMany and ManyToOne relations in order to get quicker search queries? Shall I just leave the default relations, to use OneToMany(mappedBy=...). Or is there some other way it shall be used for optimum result.

I got a tree of entities, and want to load all relations below any given node as quick as possible.

Answer (score -2):

I can't tell if you are talking about search or loading of object graphs.

A number of things will improve performance for loading of object graphs.

1)  Indexes on the database tables.
2)  Tuning the fetch strategy; avoid n+1 selects.
3)  2nd level caching

Indexes should always help you, and significantly too.   Tuning the fetch strategies should help you, and 2nd level caching might help you.  For the second and third, you will have to gather some metrics to determine the optimal path.

When you say  you

> want to load all relations below any given node as quick as possible.

just be careful not to load too much data at once.  Sometimes it's better to write optimized hql to load a summary of the object graph to present to the user, and then when the user selects individual items, load the full object.

Comment: Mm.. vice versa: you should avoid non n+1 selects. If you use joins, you don't hit cache and this reduces the performance significantly if you read more often than writing. General rule: use lazy=true & fetch=select unless you have not usual requirement.

Comment: what do you mean "vice versa".

Comment: You advised to avoid n+1 selects and to use joins. Vice versa means that you actually should avoid joins in common case and use selects or sub-selects in order to leverage 2nd level cache.

Comment: avoid n+1 selects - you know another way to avoid n+1 besides joins?

Comment: can someone please explain to me why this is getting downvoted?

Comment: My simple-minded guess is that you need to improve your answer.  Maybe more details for each of your three suggestions.  It's a good question that I imagine many developers have.

Comment: randy, thank you for the insight.  It's considered courteous to explain why the downvote occurred.  I don't think there is anything technically incorrect about my answer  @ctapobep thought I was saying the OP should use joins, but quite clearly I am not.  Although it might make sense, depending on the situation

Comment: Yap, sorry, I didn't think about batches. But anyway TC was asking about the difference in performance between OTM & MTO :)

Comment: Can you use an optional join startegy, like telling the entity manager to skip the joins and use select or do I have to defined multiple entites with the different search strategies in them?